# Copy & Paste Table to MS Word using specific CSS (clipboard.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy-paste, clipboard.js

I am struggling with the following: I am trying to copy a simple HTML table to MS Word (A4 page size) by using clipboard.js. This works generally fine.

The table width ist set to 100% in CSS, but in MS Word it extends outside the page. Is there any way to define a CSS rule that applies 100% width in the browser and fits in Word (15,99 cm)?

So what I would like to achieve:
CSS in Browser: width: 100%;
CSS for copying to WORD: width: 15,99cm;

I tried using @media queries (to apply the CSS only in the browser), but had no luck. Any other ideas? Preferably in pure CSS.

Thanks :-)

```js
new ClipboardJS('.btn');
```

```css
.resultsTable {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.6/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<!-- Target -->
<table id="foo" class="resultsTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #eeeeee; font-weight: bold; width: 100%;" colspan="4">
<p><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">"Unentschieden&rdquo;-Antworten</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold; width: 50%;" width="50%">
<p><strong>Skala</strong></p>
</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; width: 10%;" width="10%">
<p><strong>RW</strong></p>
</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; width: 10%;" width="10%">
<p><strong>PR</strong></p>
</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; width: 30%;" width="30%">
<p><strong>Text</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<p>Schule</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>18</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>90-100</p>
</td>
<td width="30%">
<p>extrem &uuml;ber &Oslash;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<p>Freizeit</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>18&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">90-100</td>
<td width="30%">
<p>extrem &uuml;ber &Oslash;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<p>Familie</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>18</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>90-100</p>
</td>
<td width="30%">
<p>extrem &uuml;ber &Oslash;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<p>Gesamt</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>54</p>
</td>
<td width="10%">
<p>90-100</p>
</td>
<td width="30%">
<p>extrem &uuml;ber &Oslash;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
    COPY
</button>
```

Comment: Can you add example code to your question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I added some example code above. It seems like the actual width of the table in the browser window (try the snippet in full size) is used in Word..

Comment: How does it paste if you remove the `width: 100%` instruction and just let it take up the dimensions it needs?

Comment: The pasting works, but it doesn‘t look the way I want it on my website (full-width) :-)
Maybe it's possible to put it in a container that stretches the table to full-width, but isn't part of the copy?!

Comment: Yeah... I intuitively feel that you may have limited control over this, i.e. how it ends up in Word, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so - but maybe somebody has an idea for a workaround? As an idea: display in 100% width and add a function to the button to change the width to 15,99cm for 1ms, copy, change width back to 100%. What do you think about the approach? Any hint how to achieve That?

Comment: Sure, that sounds viable as an option. Listen for a button click, apply the width change, write to clipboard, then undo width change.

Comment: Could you maybe provide me with a coding example as a starting point?
Thanks :-)

Comment: This is what I cam up with regarding adding and removing class: https://jsfiddle.net/fc5zjnsm/2/
But I can't get it to work combining it with copying both tables...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pucf69qy/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really know what you want to show me with it?
I am trying to fire one function by pressing a button, that does the following (in this order):
(1) add new CSS class
(2) copy both tables to clipboard using clipboard.js
(3) remove new CSS class
The Code I provided in the question is how I copy it (works only with one table) and my jsfiddle is my approach assigning a class. I am struggling with combining both into one function...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by simply defining width as an html attribute for the table and not as a css style:

```
<table width="100%">
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/8za2sv6r/